# wp_enqueue_media problem

Tags: ajax, uploads, media, wp-enqueue-script

I am trying to build up a form where user can request some post information including feature image. For uploading the image i have used wp_enqueue_media() which works nicely in all free themes locally but when i install it in main server(premium theme) i got below error through firebug-console. 
Please check the error screenshot:

[image]

When i click on the error link it shows me the 'plupload.full.min.js' file which locates to `wp-include/js/plupload/` folder.

I don't understand actually why i am getting this error. I used below function to include  `wp_enqueue_media()` through plugin folder:

```
 function add_my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_media();

 }

 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_scripts');
```

I need your kind help to get rid of this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post all your code? It's not possible to determine what you're doing from just what you've posted

Comment: Actually this is page ONLOAD error not after submitting or clicking the UPLOAD button. Is there any way to attach zip file here, because it would be easy if i give you the files. I mean plugin folder.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood my comment, I was talking about what you posted here, not posting your form in your code

Comment: sorry if i misunderstood, but i wanted to tell that the code is huge, so i posted here the actual part how i enqueued `wp_enqueue_media` in my plugin file. I am not sure which part will be suitable for you to understand error occurring code ? That is why asking you to see my full plugin folder/files.

Comment: oh..yes. I think i found the culprit plugin which interrupt to stop working for wp_media. That is 'Autoptimize' plugin. It is compressed all core file js so got that error. Thanks for your Comments @Tom J Nowell :)